# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working as intended - AngularJS cakePHP 3.0

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, cakephp-3.0, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a angularJS application with the web services written in cake PHP 3.0.

While implementing CSRF I ran into an issue where the 'set-cookie' header was not being read. After going through a few posts on stackoverflow, I added 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' to true and had 'withCredentials' to true on client side.

```
 $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
 $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
 $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
 $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

But this did not work. So I tried changing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header from localhost to "http://google.com" and hosted the code on the server.

Doing this I was expecting an error to be thrown on the browser but nothing happened. A screen shot of the service call [embedded here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnjJu.png).